# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null - Three.js

Tags: three.js, typeerror

I've trying to draw the square wall by getting mouse clicks coordinates and extrude it.
I've  picking  up the mouse coordinates by clicking at the scene.

```js
var onDocumentMouseDown = function ( event ) 
    {
        //update the mouse variable
        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5);
        vector.unproject( camera );
        var dir = vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize();
        var distance = - camera.position.z / dir.z;
        var pos = camera.position.clone().add( dir.multiplyScalar( distance));
        console.log('mouse_x ' + pos.x + ' mouse_y ' + pos.y);
        if (clickCount <= 3){
            coord[clickCount] = {'x' : pos.x, 'y' : pos.y};
            clickCount ++;
        } else {
        //make new wall and stop function
            newshape = new THREE.Shape();
            shape.moveTo(coord['0'].x ,coord['0'].y);
            shape.lineTo(coord['0'].x, coord['1'].y);
            shape.lineTo(coord['2'].x, +coord['2'].y);
            shape.lineTo(coord['3'].x, coord['3'].y);
            shape.lineTo(coord['0'].x, coord['0'].y);
            var newextrudeSettings = {
            //*******/
            };
        }
```

And when I've recived four coordinates, three.js throw the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>       at Object.triangulateShape (three.js:26140)
>       at ExtrudeGeometry.addShape (three.js:26330)
>       at ExtrudeGeometry.addShapeList (three.js:26235)
>       at new ExtrudeGeometry (three.js:26211)
>       at HTMLDocument.onDocumentMouseDown (script.js:116)

Comment: `shape.lineTo(coord['0'].x, coord['1'].y);`shouldn't it be as `shape.lineTo(coord['1'].x, coord['1'].y);`? and why not to use indices of elements as integers instead of strings: `coord['0'].x` -> `coord[0].x`, for example?

Comment: and what does `+coord['2'].y` mean?

Comment: coord -> is object of coords. 
coord['0'].x and coord['0'].y its first clicks coord.
coord['0'] is name of fist item of object
--
> shouldn't it be as shape.lineTo(coord['1'].x, coord['1'].y);
Mayby, but in my other code it stell draw the rectangle wall

Comment: Yes, I got it. Can you make a jsfiddle or codepen example. I can't recreate your error. Though, I use `THREE.Raycaster()` and a plane to find points of intersection and build a `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry()`, so everything works totally fine in my code.

Comment: Yep, As soon as possible. 
I've recive the  points of intersection, but when I trying to buil rectangle with shape.lineTo and ExtrudeGeometry it throw that error.
jsfiddle, I'll make jsfiddle a little bit later.
GIT from yesterday https://github.com/wwwork/three.js

Comment: You need click to add wal and click 4 times - looks like you add point of rectangle for extrude
https://jsfiddle.net/wwwork/n8qprwxh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find points of intersection I prefer to use `THREE.Raycaster()` (though I've never used `THREE.Projector()` for this purpose).

This is the result of my code:
[image]

I hope I got your conception. Thus, all the stuff you need is here:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects;
var controlPoints = [];
var clickCount = 0;

function onMouseDown(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects); // objects is an array which contains just the mesh of the plane
  if (intersects.length > 0) { 
    if (clickCount <= 3) { // I took your idea of 4 clicks
      controlPoints[clickCount] = intersects[0].point.clone(); // add a control point to the array

      // visualization of a control point
      var cp = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.125, 16, 12), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "red"}));
      cp.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
      scene.add(cp);

      clickCount++;
    } else { // on the fifth click we'll create our wall
      shape = new THREE.Shape();
      shape.moveTo(controlPoints[0].x, -controlPoints[0].z);
      shape.lineTo(controlPoints[1].x, -controlPoints[1].z);
      shape.lineTo(controlPoints[2].x, -controlPoints[2].z);
      shape.lineTo(controlPoints[3].x, -controlPoints[3].z);
      shape.lineTo(controlPoints[0].x, -controlPoints[0].z);
      var extrudeSettings = {
        steps: 1,
        amount: 2,
        bevelEnabled: false
      };
      var extrudeGeom = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);
      extrudeGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
      var wall = new THREE.Mesh(extrudeGeom, new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: "gray"
      }));
      scene.add(wall);
      controlPoints = []; // we clear the array of control points
      clickCount = 0; // and reset the counter of clicks
    };
  };
};
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/uc1Ldb14/) example. 4 clicks for setting control points, the fifth click creates a wall, and so on.

Comment: I've seen that I've done the mistake. I've use variable of previously created shapes. And it works with THREE.Vector2() and  THREE.Vector3
thanks. god bless you!

Comment: You're welcome) Mark the answer as accepted, please, if it solved your problem.